# Launch job from remote to secured jenkins

Tags: jenkins

i need lauch a job in a secuered jenkins from remote, i have tried with api token, instead launching job it show a jenkins login page. The URL that i use is:

> http://user:api_token@server_jenkins:8080/job/name_build/build?delay=0sec

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: need to able `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` to project page and insert any token.
The request URL is:

> http://user:api_token@server_jenkins:8080/job/name_build/build?token=token_insert_to_project

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using curl command as well. create an API token for the jenkins Job and use it to trigger the job. you can use jenkins user password for this as well.

[image]

command would be

```
curl -I -u auto:<user_api_token> http://<jenkins_Server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

results would be
[image]

for more information 
[how to trigger jenkins job via curl command remotely](https://serverfault.com/questions/888176/how-to-trigger-jenkins-job-via-curl-command-remotely/888248#888248)