# how to trigger jenkins job via curl command remotely

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have tried to execute(trigger) jenkins job (not a parameterized job) via curl command by using below methods but it showing these results. my jenkins version is Jenkins 2.73.3

```
curl -X POST -u jenkins_user_name:jenkins_user_passwd http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/build
```

But it says Forbidden 403
[image]

Therefore, I have created a Authentication Token for the Job
[image]

```
curl -X POST http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

It's also giving the same error. it says Forbidden 403

After that , I have created an API Token for jenkins User and tried.
[image]

```
curl -X POST -u auto:testingdae6dc22a73048e6d596e7b0 http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

But It also the same , it says Forbidden 403

Actually I have followed this answer as well. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/  this is also not worked for me.

**every time , It's 403 forbidden. I think I couldn't authenticate jenkins user properly.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

found the answer.  Actually those steps are correct. I would like to mention the correct steps.

Create a user in Jenkins, you can use that user password or API token for trigger Jenkins job. But creating an API token for that user is much better. But both ways working fine.

But you have to create an Authentication token for Jenkins Job

[image]

**Using Password**

```
curl -I -u auto:<userpasswd> http://<jenkins_server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

**Using an API Token**

Create an API token for that Jenkins user
[image]

```
curl -I -u auto:<user_api_token> http://<jenkins_Server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

these are the results, using **jenkins user Password** and **jenkins user API token**.

[image]

Actually you can send this request , without "-I" as well.

```
curl -u auto:<jenkins_user_token> http://<jenkins_server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf

curl -u auto:<jenkins_user_password> http://<jenkins_server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
```

Comment: Just tried this... I added an Auth-token and used it with `curl -u auto:<jenkins_user_token> http://<jenkins_server>/job/test/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf` and got `<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/hailo_ci_pull_request/build. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: seems like you have entered the wrong authentication token. please check this part "token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf" with your authentication token.

Comment: I used my authentication token that I generated from the API token in my user tab - http://<IP>/user/<my_name>/configure

Comment: I'm running an _Execute shell_ build step to start a job on the very same Jenkins (v2.249.1) instance. The `user:token` version works (even without the `token` query parameter, now wonder: it's for _Trigger builds remotely_, I'm working locally): `'/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/curl' -I -s -S -u jenkins:11e73355c68426b1bd0a4616d189d5bc2f \
  -X POST http://localhost:8083/job/$Project_To_Build/build`. The `user:pwd` version doesn't: `'/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/curl' -I -s -S -u jenkins:jenkins \
  -X POST http://localhost:8083/job/$Project_To_Build/build` – _HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden_.

Answer (score 2):

**Fast Forward to 2023**

You need to pass 2 tokens to execute your job remotely from a script/bash.
You need:

1. apiToken to authenticate your identity. This value is created from JENKINS_URL/me/configure . Also check [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/) for documentation
2. Another Job authentication token which you create when you enable 'Trigger builds remotely'.

Below is a sample to execute job with 2 parameters, you can tweak to get your done.

```bash
PARAM1_VALUE=<param1_value>
PARAM2_VALUE=<param2_vale>
USERNAME=dummy_user_name
JENKINS_URL="http://10.xxx.x.xxx:8080"
JOB_TOKEN="<value>" # you create this token when you enable Job>Configure>Build Triggers>Trigger builds remotely
LOGIN_API_TOKEN="<value>" #get this value from JENKINS_URL/me/configure 

curl -L --user $USERNAME:$LOGIN_API_TOKEN "$JENKINS_URL/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?token=$JOB_TOKEN&param1_name=$PARAM1_VALUE&param2_name=$PARAM2_VALUE"
```

Answer (score 1):

To configure these permissions:

- Click `Manage Jenkins`
- Click `Configure Global Security`
- Remove `Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits`
- Click `save`

Comment: Sounds like this would undermine the security of your system. Do you really want every website you visit to be able to run jobs on your Jenkins install?

Comment: You should use tokens instead of doing that. Security first !!!!